# Masking animation not working

Tags: html, css

Trying to make an animation where there is one image on the  'bottom layer' which is panning from left to right and on top an other image that contains transparent regions.  This to create a sort of masking effect.

For some reason this animation does not show when the applied divs are within the container/wrapper div.  On the other hand .. when outside the set div-structure, all seems to work fine, so my impression is that it must have something to do with the positioning of my divs ...

Anyone who can assist this newbee to get back on track again ?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hermanlens/BQPK5/

My html-markup:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="pagina">
        <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-anchor"></i><br /><span class="menutekst">Welkom</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-users"></i><br /><span class="menutekst">Team</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-cogs"></i><br /><span class="menutekst">Diensten</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-bullhorn"></i><br /><span class="menutekst">Nieuws</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa-phone"></i><br /><span class="menutekst">Contact</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="banner">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="panning"></div>
    </div>
</div>
        <div id="inhoud">
            Dit is de inhoud
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="zijbalk">Dit is de zijbalk</div>
    <div id="footer">Dit is de footer</div>
    </div>

    <div id="banner">
    <div id="box">
        <div id="panning"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

My CSS ...

```
    /* --------- Begin Imports ---------*/
@import 'reset.css';
@import 'font-awesome.css';
/* --------- Einde Imports ---------*/


/* --------- Begin Algemeen ---------*/
body{
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 960px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div#container{
    background-color: #fafafa;

}
/* --------- Einde Algemeen ---------*/

/* --------- Begin Pagina div ---------*/
div#pagina{
    /*background-color: orange;*/
    width: 760px;
    float: left;

}

/* --------- Begin menu ---------*/
div#menu{
    width:760px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #3194F7;
    font-style:normal;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
}
div#menu ul{
    font-size: 1em;
}
div#menu li{
    line-height: 1.1em;
    display: inline-block;
}
div#menu i{
    font-family: 'fontawesome', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-style:normal;
}
div#menu a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fafafa;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
div#menu a:hover{
    background-color:#3194f7; 
    color:#0000ff;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 25px black;
    border-left: 1px solid #3194f7;
    border-right: 1px solid #3194f7;
  transition: background .25s ease-in;
}
.menutekst{
    color: #fafafa; 
}
/* --------- Einde menu ---------*/
/* --------- Begin Banner ---------*/

#banner {
    width: 700px;

}

#box {
    background: url(../img/bannervoor.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    height: 100px;
}

#panning{
    background: #fff url(../img/containers.png) repeat bottom;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative; /* om z kunnen in te stellen*/
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-animation: pan 40s infinite linear;
    animation: pan 40s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pan {
    0% {
        background-position: 320px bottom;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: left bottom;
    }
}

@keyframes pan {
    0% {
        background-position: 160px bottom;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: left bottom;
    }
}




/* --------- Einde Banner ---------*/



div#inhoud{
    background-color: cyan;
}

/* --------- Einde Pagina div ---------*/
div#zijbalk{
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
div#footer{
    background-color: purple;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: The image that you set in the panning element background is not available (404)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/dustindowell/HruWx/

You needed to actually move the divs around rather than just turning the background into a carousel.

**CSS**

```
#banner {
    width: 700px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#box {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/160x120/000&text=Cold-Person);
    height: 100px;
}
#panning {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/160x120/&text=Warm-Blanket);
    height: 100px;
    /* om z kunnen in te stellen*/
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-animation: pan 10s;
    animation: pan 10s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pan {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(700px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
@keyframes pan {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(700px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}
```